# web transactions having sql performance or accuracy issue

Tags: mysql, sql, web-applications, transactions, query-performance

This is the story:

When there are 2 concurrent withdrawal $10 in the same account and the account has total only $10.

Result: both withdrawal success, account balance is -$10.

If I make the query like below:

```
UPDATE table
SET amount = amount - 10
WHERE (amount-10 > 0) AND id = 123;
```

it will be safe and accurate, only one of the withdraws will success.

Will there be performance issues, since the amount can't be indexed?

Comment: You probably already have a primary key on your `id` column. You don't need any more indexes in this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the query as:

```
 UPDATE table
    SET amount = amount - 10
    WHERE amount > 10;
```

Then an index can be used.  I do think you should limit the `update` only to the given account:

```
 UPDATE table
    SET amount = amount - 10
    WHERE account = @account AND amount > 10;
```

Then an index on `account` can always be used.

Comment: Oh, one more question.
is this query
UPDATE table
    SET amount = amount - 10
    WHERE amount > 10 AND account = @account;
same as 
UPDATE table
    SET amount = amount - 10
    WHERE account = @account AND amount > 10;

Comment: @user3581646 . . . Yes, they are the same.

Comment: I'll take Roland's Comment over Gordon's Answer.  But only if `id` is the PK.